# Python PIL every character same width

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw some text onto a picture by using PIL package with python. Is there a way that I can draw every character of the same width?

Thanks!

Comment: Use font with constant character width.

Answer (score 1):

I got that after think for a while, the following piece is what I used:

```
   for num, (text, color) in enumerate(wrap):
        if num==12:
            current_h=0
        if num<12:
            sw=0
        else:
            sw=MAX_W/2
        w,h=d.textsize(text.decode('gbk'), font=f)
        print list(text)
        for char in list(text):
            d.text((10+sw, current_h), char.decode('gbk'), font = f, fill = color)
            sw+=10
        current_h+=h
        print w,h
```